# Spring MV ajax form with serialize

Tags: ajax, spring, forms, spring-mvc, controller

I am trying call a spring mvc controller from a form in my page, this my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editor/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResourceDTO create(@RequestBody ResourceCreateDTO dto)
            throws Exception {
        ResourceDTO responseDTO = null;
        //Add the resourceCreate and gets the responseDTO.
        return responseDTO;

    }
```

This my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: context + "/editor/create",
            data: $("#createForm").serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success:function(result){

            },
            error:function(){

            }
        });
```

I'm getting this response: `HTTP 415`

This mi form call data (From developer view on Chrome):

```
resource-id:1006
resource-name:asdf
resource-description:asdfasdf
resource-folder:0
resource-folder-type:1000
resource-scene-width:
resource-scene-height:
```

I only have to use filled fields in this option. Not problem for empty fields.

Mi `ResourceCreateDTO` (serializable) have this fields:

```
private Integer resourceTypeId;
private Integer resourceId;
private String resourceName;
private String resourceDescription;
private Integer folderId;
private Integer resourceType;
private Integer sceneWidth;
private Integer sceneHeight;
/**GETTERS AND SETTERS**/
```